# Can you alias an array of T through a struct of T, similar to how std::complex<T>[N] can alias T[N * 2]?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing, type-punning

Since C++11 `std::complex<T>[n]` is guaranteed to be aliasable as `T[n*2]`, with well defined values. Which is exactly what one would expect for any mainstream architecture.

Is this guarantee achievable with standard C++ for my own types, say `struct vec3 { float x, y, z; }` or is it only possible with special support from the compiler?

Comment: We have a special language exception to type aliasing for a standard library type? Learn something new every day.

Comment: @JanSchultke I'd argue this question has superior answers and more insightful discussion compared to the question you closed it in favor of.

Comment: @yurikilochek I've added an answer to the dupe target which hopefully raises the quality of the target Q&A. Regardless, if a question is a duplicate but provides higher quality answers than the dupe target, the right approach is flagging it and asking a moderator to flip the duplication around, rather than reopening it as if there was no duplication. There is a significant amount of Q&As that are ultimately about aliasing between a struct and an array.

Comment: I agree that the dupe target wasn't a great candidate for being the canonical question prior to the new answer though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The compiler must inspect `reinterpret_cast`s and figure out that (standard library) specializations of `std::complex` are involved. We cannot conformably mimic the semantics.

I think it's fairly clear that treating three distinct members as array elements is not going to work, since pointer arithmetic on pointers to them is extremely restricted (e.g. adding 1 yields a [pointer past-the-end](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3)).

So let's assume `vec3` contained an array of three `int`s instead.
Even then, the underlying `reinterpret_cast<int*>(&v)` you implicitly need (where `v` is a `vec3`) does not leave you with a pointer to the first element. See the exhaustive requirements on [pointer-interconvertibility](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4):

> Two objects `a` and `b` are *pointer-interconvertible* if:
>
> - they are the same object, or
> - one is a standard-layout union object and the other is a non-static data member of that object ([class.union]), or
> - one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no
>     non-static data members, the first base class subobject of that object
>     ([class.mem]), or
> - there exists an object `c` such that `a` and `c` are pointer-interconvertible, and `c` and `b` are
>     pointer-interconvertible.
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same
>   address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer
>   to the other via a `reinterpret_­cast`. [ *Note*: **An array object
>   and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though
>   they have the same address.**  — *end note* ]

That's quite unequivocal; while we can get a pointer to the array (being the first member), and while pointer-interconvertibility is transitive, we cannot obtain a pointer to its first element.

And finally, even if you managed to obtain a pointer to the first element of your member array, if you had an array of `vec3`s, you cannot  *traverse* all the member arrays using simple pointer increments, since we get pointers past-the-end of the arrays in between. launder doesn't solve this problem either, because the objects that the pointers are associated with don't share any storage (cf [[ptr.launder]](http://eel.is/c++draft/ptr.launder#1) for specifics).

Comment: How does `launder` help? Also, why is an array not interconvertible to its first element? (These may be too broad for comments... )

Comment: @Barry The latter is perhaps inspired by an optimization. You are right concerning the former, I forgot checking that the struct is packed.

Comment: Oh joy, an array pointer that is at most a `ForwardIterator`. And one that is so dirty a hack that it requires `launder`ing at each step.

Comment: C++ could use a "layout intercompatible" assertion or something.  As in, claim that a `struct bob { int x; int y; }` is layout intercompatible with `int[2]` where `x` is `[0]` and `y` is `[1]`, and that `bob[17]` is layout intercompatible with `int[34]` in a similar way.  I say "assertion" because I simply want the power to *request* it, and if the compiler says no at least it cleanly breaks at build time.

Comment: I think there's a problem with the second `launder` in your alternative solution. The first `launder` will indeed give you a pointer to `vecarr[0].a`, but that `int` object is not an array element, so `p + 1` doesn't *point to* `vecarr[0].b`, it is a *pointer past the end* of `vecarr[0].a`. Because of this, no bytes of storage are *reachable* through `p + 1` ([\[ptr.launder\]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/ptr.launder#3)).

Comment: However, the bytes in the storage of `vecarr[0].b` would be reachable through the `launder`ed value, so the reachability requirement in [\[ptr.launder\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/ptr.launder#1) is not satisfied. As far as I understand, you basically cannot `launder` a pointer past the end and get anything useful.

Comment: @bogdan I did not look at `launder`'s wording after P0137r0. You are right. In fact, flat iteration of multi dimensional arrays is completely impossible, that's quite the pity!

Comment: @yurikilochek See the updated answer, btw. I think the motivation behind this restriction are useful optimizations like dead store elimination. Although I really don't see why complex is so special, in the general case, should you need flat iteration, you should create one single array and instead write a wrapper to facilitate access of specific "slices" (as in valarray).

Answer (score 6):

It's only possible with special support from the compiler, mostly.

Unions don't get you there because the common approach actually has undefined behaviour, although there are exceptions for layout-compatible initial sequences, and you may inspect an object through an `unsigned char*` as a special case. That's it, though.

Interestingly, unless we assume a broad and useless meaning of "below", the standard is technically contradictory in this regard:

> `[C++14: 5.2.10/1]:` *[..]* Conversions that can be performed explicitly using reinterpret_cast are listed below. No other conversion can be performed explicitly using reinterpret_cast.

The case for `complex<T>` is then not mentioned. Finally the rule you're referring to is introduced much, much later, in `[C++14: 26.4/4]`.

Comment: Not sure if that's contradictory. The clause you quoted clearly permits the conversion, but it isn't given the meaning we want just yet (that's what 26.4 does).

Comment: @Columbo: Is it "clear" though? IRTA the conversion is [arguably] not "listed below", so it cannot be performed explicitly. It's like they added a new rule to 26.4/4 but forgot to update 5.2.10.

Comment: What conversion? The conversion of one object lvalue to an lvalue reference of another object type? Isn't that like paragraph 11?

Answer (score 4):

I think it would work for a single `vec3` if your type contained `float x[3]` instead, and you ensure `sizeof(vec3) == 3*sizeof(float) && is_standard_layout_v<vec3>`. Given those conditions, the standard guarantees that the first member is at zero offset so the address of the first `float` is the address of the object, and you can perform array arithmetic to get the other elements in the array:

```
struct vec3 { float x[3]; } v = { };
float* x = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&v);  // points to first float
assert(x == v.x);
assert(&x[0] == &v.x[0]);
assert(&x[1] == &v.x[1]);
assert(&x[2] == &v.x[2]);
```

What you can't do is treat an array of `vec3` as an array of floats three times the length. Array arithmetic on the array inside each `vec3` won't allow you to access the array inside the next `vec3`. [CWG 2182](http://wg21.link/cwg2182) is relevant here.

Comment: That rather defeats the object, doesn't it?

Comment: I think this is not guaranteed to work; see my answer.